# C++ File outputting strange number, and part of code not running

Tags: c++, linux, file-io, ubuntu

Yeah.  So, I'm trying to make a code for a guessing game.  In this game, there's a hard mode.  In hard mode, you have 15 guesses, and have to guess between 1 and 500.  But my problem is this:
I'm trying to have hard mode save & display your wins/losses, but when it outputs the contents of wins.txt it outputs something like this:

```
Wins: 0x7fffee26df78
Losses: 0x7fffee26e178
```

It's really confusing me.  Here's the part of the code I have for that:

```
ifstream losses_var("losses.txt");
ifstream wins_var("wins.txt");
losses_var>> loss;
wins_var>> win;
wins_var.close();
losses_var.close();
```

Then it gets called with:

```
cout<<"Wins: "<< wins <<"\nLosses: "<< losses <<"\n"
```

If you would like to see the full source code, it's here: http://pastebin.com/gPT37uBJ

My second problem:
Hard mode won't display when you win.  That's pretty much the whole problem.  In my code, the loop for asking users for input uses 
    while (guess != randNum)
So at the end bracket I have what I want the code to display when a user wins, but it just doesn't run.  It just *stops*.  I would like it if someone could help me with this.  The line that has the bug is line 97 through 105.  Again, source code is here: http://pastebin.com/gPT37uBJ

Comment: I would suggest your first port of call be a debugger - it's probably the most important skill a developer can have. Look at what the variables have in them .... and what code paths are taken

Comment: What do you mean "I would suggest your first port of call be a debugger"?  Sorry, it didn't make much sense.

Comment: "Look at what the variables have in them .... and what code paths are taken" - it should answer your question as to whats wrong in your code...

Comment: @Predictability A debugger is a tools that will let you run your code line by line and let you see the values of variables as you go. A debugger is the #1 tool for debugging C++ programs. You should learn how to use one, there will be one that comes with your compiler/IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others have already answered the output problem (`win` vs. `wins`). The other problem is probably in your logic of `while` loop nesting. The outer loop (`while (guess != randNum)`) starts, but its body contains the entire inner loop (`while (guesses_left != 0)`). This means that the outer condition is not checked again until the inner loop terminates, which means you've run out of guesses. Also note that if you guess correctly, inner loop will never terminate. You probably want something like this:

```
while (guesses_left > 0) {
  // input user's guess
  if (guess < randNum) {
    // process it
  } else if (guess > randNum) {
    // process it
  } else {
    // it's equal, user won
    // do what's necessary for a win
    return 0;
  }
}
// ran out of guesses
// do what's necessary for a loss
return 0;
```

Comment: @Predictability If it works for you, you might want to accept one of the answers that solved the issue (john's or mine).

Comment: What do you mean I might want to accept one of the answers that solved the issue?  Both of you solved a different problem.

Comment: @Predictability I was referring to how SO works (see [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)). There's a tick mark next to answers to your questions. Clicking this tick mark lets you mark one (and only one) answer as "accepted." It's part of the site ettiquette to do so and interacts with the reputation system.

Answer (score 1):

You've got your variable names confused

```
cout<<"Wins: "<< wins <<"\nLosses: "<< losses <<"\n";
```

should be

```
cout<<"Wins: "<< win <<"\nLosses: "<< loss <<"\n";
```

It's important to pick good variable names. One reason is so that you don't confuse yourself about what your variables mean (if you confuse yourself think how it's going to be for someone else looking at your code).

Comment: Good glad to help. Can't see anything obvious that answers your other question though.

Comment: Ok.  Do you think you could help with one other problem I'm having?  If wins.txt or losses.txt doesn't exist, it will automatically create wins/losses.txt and put inside them an int like 1026344.  Is there a way to make it automatically put in 0 instead?

Comment: For your second question (code not running) the problem is the two while loops. You only need one while loop for this problem, `while (guess not right && more guesses left) { ... }`. It's one while loop with a complex condition, not two while loops.

Comment: For your third problem (file doesn't exist) you should check when you open the file to read the files whether that worked. If the file doesn't exist then the file open will fail, then you can assign 0 to the int instead of trying to read from a file that doesn't exist. Something like `ifstream wins_var("wins.txt"); if (wins_var.is_open()) { wins_var >> win; wins_var.close(); } else win = 0;`

Comment: You really should clean up those variable names before you do anything else, `win`, `wins`, `wins_var` etc. is extremely confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing your variables `win` and `loss` to `cout`. From your pasted code, I can see that `wins` and `losses` are ofstream objects, which means you are probably seeing addresses there. I would advise you to choose more informative variable names to avoid hard to spot mistakes like this.